# split file lines based on first field

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have file with content like below and want to convert my output like below

- Input

  ```
  1,a,b,c
  2,b,c
  3,e,f
  4,l
  ```
- Required output

  ```
  1,a
  1,b
  1,c
  2,b
  2,c
  3,e
  3,f
  4,l
  ```

Values on first field is unique and no duplicate lines for 1st field in the input.

I am new to scripting and not sure how can we do this.

Comment: Similar (but not exactly the same): [awk command to delimit the second column](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/372253)

Comment: Should that last `4,1` (four-one) be `4,l` (four-ell) like in the input file?

Comment: it is 4-l(ell) both in input and output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` and loop through the fields starting with 2:

```
awk -F, '{ OFS=FS; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i }' file
```

Output:

```
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,b
2,c
3,e
3,f
4,l
```

Comment: Don't keep setting OFS for every input line, just do it once when you set FS: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i }' file`

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you would do

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*,)([^,]*),/\1\2\n\1/;P;D' file
```

Note that using `\n` in the replacement string works just for GNU `sed`. On other systems you would need to use an actual newline, preceeded by a backslash:

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*,)([^,]*),/\1\2\
\1/;P;D' file
```

- `-E` means extended regular expressions, so I can use `()` instead of `\(\)`. Just for readability
- `[^,]*` matches a string without a comma, so it matches one field
- Thus, `[^,]*,[^,]*,` matches the first two fields. I did put `()` around the fields so I can reuse them as `\1` and `\2` in the replacement
- The `s` command replaces the first two fields with themselves, adds a newline and repeats the first field in the new line. So the line is split in two: `1,a,b,c` will be one line with `1,a` and another one with `1,b,c`
- Now `P` prints the first line in the buffer (we know that it's already fine for printing)
- `D` deletes the first line from the buffer and starts the script over if there is anything left in the buffer after removing. So the remaining `1,b,c` will again get split into the `1,b` and `1,c` lines.
- If there is only one `x,y` left, the pattern will not match anymore, so no newline gets inserted and `sed` doesn't cycle, but will continue with the next line

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --c2n --ofs "," --implicit-csv-header then reshape -r "[^1]" -o item,value then cut -x -f item input.txt
```

you will have in output

```
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,b
2,c
3,e
3,f
4,l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task various ways, as shown below:

```
$ sed -e ':a
    s/,/\n/2;/\n/!b
    P;s/,.*\n/,/;ba
' file.csv
```

**Explanation:**

We try to change the second comma to a newline. If not possible => the pattern space had less than two and hence should be handed over to stdout.

OTW, we print the leading two comma-separated fields, then remove the second field such that the third now becomes the second nd so on.

```
$ perl -F,  -lane '
    my $f1 = shift @F;
    print join ",", $f1, $_ for @F;
' file.csv
```

**Explanation:**

Split each line into fields based on comma and `perl`  will store the fields in the array @F.
The first field we shift off the array @F and store in the scalar `$f1`. Then progressively print the elements of the array.

```
$ perl -F\(,\) -lane '
    my $f1 = shift @F;
    print $f1, splice @F, 0, 2 while @F > 1 ;
' file.csv

$ perl -F, -lane 'print $F[0], $_ for /,(?:(?!,).)*/g' file.csv

$ sed -Ee 's/,?[^,]*/[&] /g'  file.csv |
   dc -e "
   [q]sq
   [SMlN1+sNz1<a]sa
   [dnLMn10anlN1-dsN0<b]sb
   [?z0=q0sNlaxlbxclcx]sclcx
"
```

**Result:**

```
 1,a
 1,b
 1,c
 2,b
 2,c
 3,e
 3,f
 4,l
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command  and it worked fine

```
count_line=`awk '{print NR}' p.txt| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`
for((i=1;i<=$count_line;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i{print $1}' p.txt`;k=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i{print NF}' p.txt`; for ((z=2;z<=$k;z++)); do awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" -v z="$z" -F "," 'NR==i{print j","$z}' p.txt; done; done
```

output

```
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,b
2,c
3,e
3,f
4,l
```