# Add new lines based on the columns of a tab delimited file

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a tab-separated file like this:

```
211845  032
215979  002   071
217783  143   156   169
219750  111
```

For the lines that have multiple tab separated entries, I want to add new lines based on the value of column one.  Here is my desired result:

```
211845  032
215979  002
215979  071
217783  143
217783  156
217783  169
219750  111
```

Appreciate any ideas, this one has me stumped.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? [split file lines based on first field](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532092)/

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`, loop for the fields after the first one, for every line, and print a new line for every field.

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
```

Output:

```
211845  032
215979  002
215979  071
217783  143
217783  156
217783  169
219750  111
```

This way, we discard any lines blank or having only one field, which is probably what you want. In order to keep them as they are, a modification could be:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF<2 {print; next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `GNU sed` making use of its extended regex mode `-E` to aid in writing somewhat easy-to-read regexes.

```bsh
sed -E '
  s/\t/\n/2;T
  s/^([^\t]+\t).*\n/&\1/
  P;D
' file
```

---

Outputs:

```
211845  032
215979  002
215979  071
217783  143
217783  156
217783  169
219750  111
```

---

- If a line has less than 2 TABs, display it unmodified by means of the T command.
- Display the first pair with the P command, stitch the first field at the back of the first pair.
- This process goes on until we are left with one TAB, which then is printed by means of furst step.

---